# Does AFNetworking 2.0 support iOS 6.0?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

AFNetworking 2.0 was announced last week. But I find different requirements for AFNetworking 2.0.

[README.md](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/2.0) tells it requires either iOS 7.0 and above, while [AFNetworking 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide) tells it requires either iOS 6.0 and above.

Dose AFNetworking 2.0 support iOS 6.0?

Comment: One way or the other, you should file a bug report about this.

Comment: +1 to cancel out the down vote. This *is* confusing as the docs and other places disagree with each other.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Accoding to [the CocoaPods podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/AFNetworking/2.0.0-RC3/AFNetworking.podspec), you can simply use AFN 2.0 but not include the `NSURLSession` related files.

For example if you use CocoaPods (if you don't, you should really consider doing it, it's awesome!), simply use this on your Podfile to get AFN 2.0 without `NSURLSession`-related features:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

This will only get the `"Core"` subspec, which supports the deployment target 6.0 for iOS (`s.ios.deployment_target = '6.0'` in the podspec) and does not integrate `NSURLSession`-related files. So this will be compatible with your project using an iOS6 or greater deployment target.

---

If you later wish to drop the 6.0 support on your project and take advantage of the `NSURLSession` capabilities, you can add the `NSURLSession` subspec to your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0' # Core, without NSURLSession, compatible with iOS6
pod 'AFNetworking/NSURLSession', '~> 2.0' # Add NSURLSession features, only compatible with iOS7
```

You can see in the `podspec` that adding the `NSURLSession` subspec will add the `s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'` requirement as a consequence, requiring your project's deployment target to be 7.0 or greater too of course, as you could expect.

---

[EDIT] Since my answer, Mattt updated its code and podspec so that you can get the `NSURLSession` subspec even when targeting iOS6. See [this pull request on its github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1412) (and other ones related).
So now you can get the `NSURLSession` subspec even for you iOS6-min projects, and just conditionally call them at runtime only `if ([NSURLSession class])` is true.

Comment: Awesome! That's what I want! I did use CocoaPods (a CocoaPods newbie), but I am not sure which AFNetworking version I could use for my iOS 6 project.

Comment: Use `2.0`, but don't use the `NSURLSession` subspec, just the default one (as explained in my answer).

Comment: This is what I tried, but `~> 2.0` version cannot be found in CocoaPods. So I used `2.0.0RC3` instead, but this includes `NSURLSession` without `AFNetworking/NSURLSession` subspec.

Comment: If you have a problem with using AFN with CocoaPods and all, prefer filing an issue on mattt's GitHub repo, it will be a more appropriate place to ask such questions than SO for that.

Comment: It's so sad we cannot use AFNetworking and AFNetworking/NSURLSession in a project with ios6 compatibility and decide to call the new class or not according to the ios version…

Comment: @Gros I don't get it? Of course you can, as you was always be able to do (see the Apple documentation "SDK Compatibility Guide")

Comment: @AliSoftware If you create a project with the two pods lines (AfNetworking & AfNetworking/NSURLSession) you cannot have a deployment target of 6.0 and so you cannot do a test to trigger a specific code for ios6 which is not using the new NSURLSession api and for iOS7 use the new features. 
It is due to the way it is implemented "#if (defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 70000)"… whereas I'm able to do if I'm implementing by myself the NSURLSession feature…
I don't understand why it has been not like this.

Comment: I asked the question on the AFNetworking Github just to understand : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1437

Comment: Yep I totally agree that's strange that Mattt did use `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` (Deployment Target) instead of `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` (Base SDK), it doesn't make any sense. I really hope he will change it, as it creates such a mess, even in my own components like [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) (whose Travis build keeps failing… just because Travis-CI still uses Xcode4 and AFN2 make this build fail :-@ whereas it shouldn't if it was properly coded). There is already 4 issues on his GitHub about it but it doesn't seems like he wants to change it :(

Comment: FYI after a lot insisted, Mattt did change its code so that AFN2.0 is able to compile for iOS6 too. See https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1412

Comment: Am I missing something?  I'm under the impression that simply by using  `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'` in my podfile that I will be able to support iOS 6, but this does not seem to be the case.  I'm still getting NSURLSession symbol not found crashes that originate from AFNetworking.

Comment: Of course, when you do this (using AFNetworking 2.0 with `NSURLSession` subspec but still having to support iOS6), you have to conditionally use `NSURLSession`-related methods in your code, like only use `AFSessionManager` class and the like only when the class exists. (See Apple's SDK Compatibility Guide for more info)

Comment: Currently trying to do this as well, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm only using `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, and just have `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.2.4'` in my Podfile. However, when running the app in the simulator on iOS 6.1 it still crashes because it can't dynamically link `_NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown`

Comment: Maybe file an issue to Mattt on its github repo. My guess is that he did add some new code to the repo since my answer, and that new code uses the `NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown` symbol, but he forgot to encapsulate it inside some `#if`...`#endif` this time, so this is a bug to tell him about.

Comment: After checking on mattt's GitHub repo, the only occurences of `NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown` I can find in his code is in `AFURLSessionManager.m`, whose whole content is embedded inside a big `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000`…`#endif`, so this code is not compiled if you are using SDK<7, and if you are using SDK7+ then that's **your** responsibility not to call anything related to `AFURLSessionManager` if `[NSURLSession class]` is `nil` (meaning that the class does not exist at runtime, because the user runs the app on iOS6 and not iOS7)

Answer (score 4):

AFNetworking 2.0 is supported in iOS 6. My problem was that I had previously installed it with the platform set to iOS 7. I fixed it by doing this:

1. Deleted everything from my `Podfile`
2. Ran `pod install`, which deleted all my pods.
3. Added everything back to my `Podfile`, with `platform :ios, '6.0'`

And I was able to still use my existing AFNetworking code with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support iOS6, except for the `NSURLSessionTask` parts, which are iOS7 only.

I was confused as well, but it looks during the transition from 1.x -> 2.0 not all the docs had yet been updated. They have been now, and it works just fine in my project that supports iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFNetworking 2.0 .Just have to ensure that the deployment target is set to 6.0 while installing using cocoa pods.I had initially installed AFNetworking when my deployment target was 7.0 .So had to remove it from cocoa pods set deployment target to 6.0 and then do install again.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use pod at all. Instead, I downloaded it and dragged the files to the project, and then encountered this problem as well. To fix it I simply deleted the `AFURLSessionManager` and `AFHTTPSessionManager` files from the project. Then it worked.