# Does AFNetworking 2.2.1 support iOS 6.0?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I use CocoaPods and AFNetworking 2.2.1, but have error "dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown" in ios 6.1

I know [Does AFNetworking 2.0 support iOS 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041584/does-afnetworking-2-0-support-ios-6-0/19041901#19041901)

I add pod 'AFNetworking/NSURLSession', '~> 2.0'   in CocoaPods, but error  "dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown" in ios 6.1.

What can i do for ios6.1?
I've done half of the project.... 
Help me please...

Comment: Reread again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041584/does-afnetworking-2-0-support-ios-6-0/19041901#19041901 it explains what to do. NSURLSession is iOS 7 and above only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added those frameworks :SystemConfiguration, Security, CFNetwork ?

Comment: This won't fix it. NSURLSession-based APIs are only available in iOS 7.

Comment: Moreover, Cocoapods links the needed framework in the *framework* group of Pods in the .xcworkspace

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking 2.X has been updated for iOS 7 and the new *NSURLSession* protocols, which are only available in iOS 7. In order to use this great toolbelt with prior versions of iOS, you have to specify in your podfile.

1. The platform version, like this `platform :ios, '6.0'`
2. The version of AFNetworking you need with the optimistic operator `~>`

So your podfile for AFNetworking should look like this on below

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
xcodeproj 'MyProject'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.8'
```

**or**

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
xcodeproj 'MyProject'
pod 'AFNetworking', '< 2.0'
```

Hope this post help !